# How to disable/enable popup with Jekyll

Tags: javascript, popup, jekyll, magnific-popup

I have a pop-up in my website that appears when you first go in. I want to allow the option to disable or enable when desired. It's a .yml file within an 'include' and I'm using Magnific Pop-Up.

Here's the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    var now, lastDatePopupShowed;
    now = new Date();

    if (localStorage.getItem('lastDatePopupShowed') !== null) {
      lastDatePopupShowed = new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('lastDatePopupShowed')));
    }

    if (((now - lastDatePopupShowed) >= (15 * 86400000)) || !lastDatePopupShowed) {
      $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
          src: '#launch-popup'
        },
        type: 'inline'
      }, 0);

      localStorage.setItem('lastDatePopupShowed', now);
    }
  });
});
```

I'd love to hear your ideas on how to solve it.

Comment: You mean to disable it from loading with a configuration flag?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**:

Wrapping the pop up itself in a Jekyll include with an if statement.

```
{% If page.popup-turned-on == true %} 

... Code for pop up 

{% endif %}
```

Then, add the following in the front matter:

```
popup-turned-on: true
```

Happy coding!

Comment: You might want to wrap that in your document ready... but yeah... that is basically what I meant. Great you got it working! +1

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    {% if site.popup %}
      /*.. JS code for popup ..*/
    {% endif %}
  });
});
```

And in your _config.yml:

```
popup: true
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. It disables all my pop-ups. Do you know if there is another way of adding a variable via the .js code?

Comment: Can you specify what exactly does not work? Is the liquid being parsed? Is the site.popup variable false? Can you provide more detail and/or a repository?

Comment: Hi there! Sorry for the super late reply, but a friend of mine showed me a solution. Sharing below so it can help someone in the future!